# Using Count Function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok I am trying to use this count function to count different sections of a case statement. This is the working code right now. It will tell me what year someone started at a school. How the school year is broken down is 200703 is Summer 07, 200801 is Fall 07, and 200802 is Spring 08. So the case statement gives me the academic school year a student started. I just need an easy way to count how many first year students are in each academic year. I tried using Count around the case statement and tried setting up different ways to count it but always came across aggregate function errors. Any help would be great. I am writing this in SQL Server 2008 R2

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.student_crs_hist.id_num,   
     sum(dbo.student_crs_hist.credit_hrs) as 'tot_credit_hrs',   
     min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)  as 'first_year',
     'Year' = CASE
     WHEN min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)in ('200703','200801','200802') Then '20007-2008'
     WHEN min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)in ('200803','200901','200902') Then '20008-2009'
     WHEN min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)in ('200903','201001','201002') Then '20009-2010'
     WHEN min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)in ('201003','201101','201102') Then '2010-2011'
     Else '2011-2012'
     END
FROM dbo.student_crs_hist,   
     dbo.degree_history 
WHERE dbo.student_crs_hist.id_num = dbo.degree_history.id_num  and  
        ((dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.YR_CDE in ('2007') and dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE in ('03')) OR 
       (dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde in ( '2008','2009','2010','2011')  AND  dbo.student_crs_hist.trm_cde in ( '01','02','03' ))OR
         (dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.YR_CDE in ('2012') and dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE in ('01','02'))) and 
      dbo.student_crs_hist.transaction_sts in ( 'C','H' )  AND  
      dbo.student_crs_hist.grade_cde in ( 'A','B','C' )  AND  
      dbo.degree_history.major_1 = 'ASBD' and
      dbo.student_crs_hist.adv_req_cde not in ('COL081','EGL082','EGL092','EGL093','MAT091','MAT092','MAT093','COM091','EGL100','REA100')  
Group By
     dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.ID_NUM 
Having
     sum(dbo.student_crs_hist.credit_hrs) >= '30' and

     (min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE) = '200703' or
     min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde) in ('2008','2009','2010','2011') or
     MIN(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.student_crs_hist.trm_cde) in ('201201','201202'))
    Order By
    min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)
```

Comment: use this entire statement as the FROM () table - then select the count of the (unaliased) column and group by the column

Answer (score 0):

Try This Approach:

```
...
SUM(
   CASE WHEN min(dbo.student_crs_hist.yr_cde+dbo.STUDENT_CRS_HIST.TRM_CDE)in ('200703','200801','200802') Then 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) as FirstYearStudents_07-08
...
```